# Vue.js How to output attribute inside html tag when attribute name is included in value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If I have a data structure that contains field attributes as follows, how can I output the `dataAttributes` value inside the html?

```
var app3 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-3',
       data: {
         field: { 
                  type: 'text,
                  name: 'First Name', 
                  class: 'form-control js-user-lookup',
                  dataAttributes: 'data-autocomplete-url=api/users data-selected=123',
                }
       }
})

<input :type="field.type"
       :id="field.name"
       :name="field.name"
       :class="field.class"
       {{field.dataAttributes}} />
```

You can't use the mustache syntax inside of html tags and I cant bind it to a data-* attribute since the attribute is part of the value e.g. data-autocomplete-url and data-selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with plain data-binding syntax. You will need to use the custom `directive`. It will look like this.

```
<input :name="field.name" v-data-binder="field.dataAttributes" />
```

Your directive definition will be something like:

```
// Register a global custom directive called `v-focus`
Vue.directive('data-binder', {
    // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
    inserted: function (el, binding) {
        // Perform data attribute manipulations here.

        // 1. Parse the string into proper key-value object
        // binding.value

        // 2. Iterate over the keys of parsed object

        // 3. Use JavaScript *dataset* property to set values
    }
})
```

You will also need `updated` hook in your directive definition to remove existing **data-*** attributes whenever the value passed to the directive changes.

Comment: thats turned out to be more complex than I thought.

Comment: @adam78, unfortunately, that is the case. What you need exists for `class` manipulation but not for attributes manipulation. Attribute binding should be predictable and hence bindings must be codified at the time of writing components. This is a must-have requirement for building large-scale applications.

Comment: is there no way to just output the value by going into the dom?

Comment: @adam78, nothing that I am aware of. There might be a small jQuery like library that you can use within the directive. But it must be done via directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily do it if you have the dataAttributes string passed as a javascript object and just bind it like that v-bind="myobject". If not possible you can transform it via a computed property
Check below example

```
<div id="app">
</div>



 var instance = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:function(){
    return {
      inputType:'password',
      fieldAttributes:"data-autocomplete-url=api/users data-selected=123"
   };
 },
  computed:{
    getDataAttributes:function(){
     var attributes = this.fieldAttributes.split(' ');

    var attributesO = {};
    for(var a=0;a<attributes.length;a++){
      var attribute = attributes[a];
      var attribute_ar = attribute.split('=');
      attributesO[attribute_ar[0]] = attribute_ar[1];
    }

     return attributesO;
    }
 },
 methods:{
   getAttribute:function(){
     alert(this.$refs.myinput.dataset.selected)
   }
  },
   template:`<div>
    <input ref="myinput" v-on:click="getAttribute" :type="inputType"  v-bind="getDataAttributes" />
    </div>`
   });
```

Comment: Check working codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqqJjM?editors=1111 and the guide on v-bind https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind